# How indexes work for below queries?

Tags: sql-server

I have created the below table with primary key:

```
create table test2
(id int primary key,name varchar(20))  

insert into test2 values
(1,'mahesh'),(2,'ram'),(3,'sham')
```

then created the non clustered index on it.

```
 create nonclustered index ind_non_name on test2(name)
```

when I write below query it will always you non clustered indexes in query execution plan.

```
select COUNT(*) from test2  
select id from test2   
select * from test2
```

Could you please help me to understand why it always use non clustered index even if we have clustered index on table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you create a non-clustered index on name, the index actually contains name and id, so it kind of contains all the table itself.
If you add another field like this:

```
create table test4
(id int primary key clustered,name varchar(20), name2 varchar(20))  

insert into test4 values
(1,'mahesh','mahesh'),(2,'ram','mahesh'),(3,'sham','mahesh')  

 create nonclustered index ind_non_name on test4(name)
```

You'll see that some of the queries will start using the clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the indexes are pretty much the same thing, since clustered index also contains the data, your clustered index is `id, name` and non clustered indexes contain the clustering key, so the non-clustered index is `name, id`.

You don't have any search criteria, so no matter which index is used, it must be scanned completely anyhow, so why should it actually use the clustered index?

If you add third field you your table, then at least `select *` will use clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing Primary Keys with clustering keys.  They are not the same. You will need to explicitly create the clustering key.

To create the clustering key on the primary key in the create statement:

```
create table test2
(id int ,name varchar(20)
 constraint PK_ID_test2 primary key clustered(id))
```

To add the clustering key to what you have already:

```
ALTER TABLE test2   
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ID_test2 primary key clustered(id)
```

Comment: Primary key is clustered by default, unless it's explicitly created as non-clustered.

Comment: I thought they might be, but had some trouble finding a reference.  I'll leave this here so the OP and others can see your comment in particular.

Comment: Here's also a reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library /aa933131%28v=sql.80%29.aspx -- that looks like SQL Server 2000, but it hasn't changed, and you can of course see it with sp_help.

Comment: Perfect!  That's what I was looking for